# Textblock and HyperlinkButton do not align correctly

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I'd like to have a hyperlink and a textblocks on the same line, however both controls act somewhat different. The hyperlink is just a few pixels more to the right, like there is a margin but it's not, is it? Just look at this piece of code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication7.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Umsatzsteuerart: " />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="Test" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Hersteller:" />
        <HyperlinkButton Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Content="Test" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="Umsatzsteuerart:" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="Test" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Shouldn't all three ui-controls be aligned to the same line? Is there a solution for this problem? HorizontalAlignment doesn't effect anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found the solution myself:**
Setting the padding of the HyperlinkButton will align the hyperlink correctly.